# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty. WHEN FULL in settings.py

Tags: python, django

Im having an issue getting my django up on a server. Here is the traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    import AuShadha.startup as startup
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/AuShadha/src/AuShadha/AuShadha/startup.py", line 19, in <module>
from AuShadha import settings
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/AuShadha/src/AuShadha/AuShadha/settings.py", line 8, in <module>
django.setup()
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/vagrant/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django    /conf/__init__.py", line 116, in __init__
raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

and here is settings.py

```
# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'jbnlwhbvwdvilibbfwlhbwhbvccvjlanoajhfjdofffofoewfbwfho'
```

This is also not my actual secret key

here is manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

def fix_reload(v):
    if '--noreload' in v: return v
    if v[1] == 'runserver':
        return v[:2] + ['--noreload'] + v[2:]
    return v

if __name__ == "__main__":
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "AuShadha.settings")


print "Trying to run custom code at startup..."
print "Loading apps and roles from configure.yaml"
import AuShadha.startup as startup
startup.run()
print "Roles for UI loaded"

from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

sys.argv = fix_reload(sys.argv)
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv
```

As per requested from some users below. I have a couple of different file architectures set up, namely inside of venv and outside if that helps anyone at all

Comment: You're using Vagrant so you might need to check the path in your manage.py and wsgi.py to point to the right settings - has to be appname.settings if file not moved to other location, but that appname has to be recognizable by Python in this specific environment.

Comment: Show us your manage.py

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
def fix_reload(v):
    if '--noreload' in v: return v
    if v[1] == 'runserver':
        return v[:2] + ['--noreload'] + v[2:]
    return v
if __name__ == "__main__":
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "AuShadha.settings")
print "Trying to run custom code at startup..."
print "Loading apps and roles from configure.yaml"
import AuShadha.startup as startup
startup.run()
print "Roles for UI loaded"
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
sys.argv = fix_reload(sys.argv)
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv